# What is v in p=IV if I want to use p=IV to calculate power loss

Tags: voltage, power, current

I know that we generally use p=I^2R to calculate power loss and if we want to use p=V^2/R, the v is voltage drop. Is it true that the v in p=IV, when calculating power loss is also voltage drop?

Thanks for answering!

Comment: technically, there is no `v` in `p=IV` ... and the equation is `P=IV`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand

Comment: \$v\$ and \$V\$ are two different variables, possibly representing two entirely different things.

Comment: @Jstola if you **MUST**  try to confuse the newcomers, in likely contrevention of the *be nice* policy, then you might wish to either decapitalise the p in your correction or go so far as to note that it's capitalised coz its the start of a "sentence". Yes? || By all means correct and inform the newcomers, but that 'advice' essentially amounts to mind games in this context. Know? :-)

Comment: Stick to the SI system and all confusion will go away. The correct formula is P = U * I.

Comment: @Lundin I'm a big supporter of the SI but I didn't think that it recommended *U* **or** *V* as the quantity symbol for EMF, but of course V is the unit symbol for the volt. IEEE recommends *V* or *E* over *U*, and recommends *U* for magnetic potential difference. Do you have a citation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, both of those V represent the voltage drop.

The formula P=(I^2)R is for the case of constant current and (V^2)/R is used for the case of constant voltage.

Considering a constant voltage source, we can see that when the resistance increases, the current decreases. Ultimately it comes down to P=IV. So at constant voltage, power is inversely proportional to resistance.

In case of constant current source, when there is increase in resistance, more voltage is dropped(Ohm's law). So again using P=IV, power is directly proportional to the voltage and voltage is directly proportional to the resistance.

It all depends on your choice.You can use all three formulas if you know all the parameters. Check it yourself.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fszc3g.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Find the current and voltage drop across each resistor. Now apply all three formulas. Compare the results.

Answer (score 2):

You really really should do a basic web search before asking questions like that, here or anywhere. The matters involved are so basic and fundamental to the subject that you cannot properly understand the answers you'll get if you don't have a look at what is readily available first. [[Get out of jail free card: In a facility where you can post to SE but cannot access web searching. Rare but possible]].

Convention for SI (System Internationale) units is:

Symbols for units which are based on names of people (usually their discoverer or proposer) are capitalised.
Hence V, A, F, ... / volt, ampere, farad, ... .

Symbols for units which are not based the names of people are not capitalised.
Hence m, s, l, ... / metre, second, lumen, ... .

Names of units are in lower case (even when named after a person) with ONE exception  .
eg  volt, ampere, farad, second, lumen, ... .

The exception is degrees Celsius.
(I'd argue that the a;most SI degrees Kelvin would be similarly treated and also the non-SI degrees Rankin and degrees Fahrenheit).

**SO**

V = Voltage. SI unit - V / volt
I = Current. SI Unit - A / ampere
R = Resistance. SI unit - \$\Omega\$ / ohm
P = Power. SI unit - W / watt

In the following I "break" the above rules re capitalisation as some of these LOOK like SI units but are not. ie R = Resistance, V = Volts, I = Amps, P = Watts.
To be SI units these would need to be \$\Omega\$, V, A, W

R = V/I - Ohm's law.
I = V/R - Ohm's law 'rearranged'
V = IR  - Ohm's law 'rearranged'

P = V x I

P = V^2/R

- ie P = V x I = V x V/R = V^2/R

P = I^2 R

- ie P = V x I = IR x I = I^2R

[The web search you could/should have done](https://www.google.com/search?q=What+is+v+in+p%3DIV+if+I+want+to+use+p%3DIV+to+calculate+power+loss+%22voltage%22+%22current%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&ei=SgpNXe3sPNHdz7sP2MuHiAs&start=160&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwjtubvSjPXjAhXR7nMBHdjlAbE48AEQ8tMDCDk&biw=2214&bih=1374)

Answer (score 1):

\$P = IV\$ is the general equation relating current and voltage to power.  Specifically it relates the current through a device and the voltage across it to the power generated or dissipated by the device.  In a resistor, the voltage and current are related with Ohm's law, \$V = IR\$.  This relates the voltage across a resistor to the current through the resistor.  Since \$V\$ and \$I\$ represent the same quantity in both equations, you can solve Ohm's law for \$V\$ or \$I\$ and substitute that to end up with \$P = V^2/R\$ and \$P = I^2R\$.  Note that these equations only work for resistances (and also complex impedances) but not for active components or other components that do not obey Ohm's law.